# Applying hosts resource in puppet to update /etc/hosts

Tags: rhel, puppet

Using `puppet`, trying with the `host` resource to update `/etc/hosts` on `node2.example.com` with the below entry

```
     master.example.com  10.134.39.245
     node2.example.com   10.134.39.246
```

For this I have created the following manifest .

```
 node 'node2.example.com'{
 host{
    'master.example.com': ip => '10.134.39.245';
    'node2.example.com': ip => '10.134.39.246';
   }
  }
```

But `/etc/hosts` is not getting edited on node2.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each host should be a separate definition. And I'm not sure about the semicolons in your snippet. Also providing aliases for your hosts is a better practice.

Maybe you could try this syntax :

```
node 'node2.example.com' {
  host { 'master.example.com': 
    ip => '10.134.39.245',
    host_aliases => 'master',
  }
  host { 'node2.example.com': 
    ip => '10.134.39.246',
    host_aliases => 'node2',
  }
}
```

Puppet CookBook : [Add a host entry](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/adding-a-host-entry.html)